# Are any of the maven goals affected by the operating system environment variables (except MAVEN_OPTS)

Tags: maven

We are seeing one developer's laptop is ending up with a testcase failing due to a library versioning mismatch.   This happens *after* the testcases had already run and the uber-jar had been created - but before the installation step.

On several other developer's machines this problem does not happen. One of the team members believes that an environment variable such as `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` may be at fault.

But .. it was my understanding / concept of the maven approach that builds should run identically across different environments - they are insulated by all environment settings except for `JVM` ones and maven-specific ones such as `MAVEN_OPTS`.

Which of the two is correct:

- Maven creates an insular o/s environment-variables - free runtime environment
- Maven tests may be affected by the runtime environment

**Update**   Specifically let's focus on the following:

- Is it possible for libraries not included in the `maven` dependencies
  to be affecting either the build or the testcases run during `test`
  and `package` phases ?

So in other words - the focus here would not be on `System.getenv` or `System.getProperties` but on the `classpath` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven does not use a Security Manager to isolate the build completely from the environment. If the build runs code that calls `System.getenv`, that code will get the value from the environment.

Some Maven plugins that launch new processes provide a means to set environment variable values, but none of them have an option to start from a clean, repeatable, environment.

If you are using the `maven-exec-plugin`, or any other plugin that launches a new process, and that process is a JVM, that JVM's classpath is indeed modifiable by environment variables or anything else. If you are launching some shell script that launches Hadoop, it will indeed respect whatever environment variables it looks at.

If you are testing code that builds new class loaders, Maven has no influence on what pathnames end up in these classloaders.

It you have code in your unit or integration tests that launches a new JVM, that will have whatever classpath the code arranges. Maven only controls the classpath of Java code run directly from Maven: slightly oversimplified, that is Maven plugins and unit tests.

Comment: Right, but go launching shell scripts from Maven, and wave goodby to all that carefullness. Or even call Java code that turns around and launches new JVM processes; Maven really cannot help you control that.

Comment: The tests are failing in one machine and not another - not talking about shell scripts.

Comment: You mentioned HADOOP_CLASSPATH, and so I hypothesize that you've got tests that run shell scripts to launch Hadoop. At this point, I'm guessing what's in your tests. I'd print out the classpath in the tests in various places.

Comment: The tests are spark only running via `scalatest`  , no explicit shell env vars and certainly no shell scripts.  The only usage of `hadoop` actually is the `HadoopFileSystem` jar file - which is used for accessing the local file system only (we do not even have any `hdfs` in the organization)

Answer (score 1):

Maven exposes environment variables as [properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) to the build environment. If one of the plugins you use relies on such a property the second of your points can happen. This should be documented on the plugin's doc page.

The [Javadoc of the `PackMojo` class of the `hadoop-maven-plugin`](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/maven-hadoop/plugin/maven-hadoop-plugin/0.20.1/maven-hadoop-plugin-0.20.1-javadoc.jar), for instance, reads:

> • The dependencies that are already present in $HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar , if present in the project's dependencies are ignored.